# Static Casting Error C2440 When Attempting to Add another Interface to COM object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, interface, com

I am attempting to add some functionality to a COM object by including another Interface called INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf. However I am running into errors when compiling. I have researched the error code and the page gave some [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2440) of the error and how to fix it but none showed an example using the [COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/687y36sx.aspx) method.

I found similar questions on here, [QUESTION 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442457/error-c2440-static-cast-cannot-convert-from-uint-thiscall-cimportprojec) and [QUESTION 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861084/casting-error-in-c) but they both refer to BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP errors and not the BEGIN_COM_MAP errors...

I am new to COM but I am working on a Project that uses it extensively. I am using another COM object for reference that uses the interface I am trying to add but now I am stuck on where to go about fixing this error. **How do I go about getting the COM object to compile or where could I look to fix the issue?**

Here is the Code

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CNvRtrProtocolXxxImpl)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(INvRtrProtocolXxxItf)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(INvRtrProtocol4Itf)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(INvComponent3Itf)
    //added the following line to add another interface
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf) //throws error 1 (C2440)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
END_COM_MAP() //throws error 2 (C2440)
```

Error 1

```
error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'CNvRtrProtocolXxxImpl::_ComMapClass *' to 'INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf *'
```

Error 2

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'ATL::_ATL_CREATORARGFUNC (__cdecl *)' to 'DWORD_PTR'
```

Comment: Have you declared the new interface in the IDL file?

Comment: Are you sure `CNvRtrProtocolXxxImpl` actually implements this new interface? You need to extend `CNvRtrProtocolXxxImpl` from it publicly, as well as add it to the Com Map.

Comment: @RichardCritten I looked at the IDL file in the other COM object that uses the interface and it doesn't add it to its coclass... it's commented out and still compiles.

Comment: @lcs Let me double check all the signatures and so on to make sure they are implemented exactly as specified by the interface...

Comment: @lcs So there is a class I extend called CRtrProtocolExBase which uses all the methods for the INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf interface. I have implemented all the those functions. This is the same class that is extended by the other COM object that implements the INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf  interface...

Comment: @lcs I think you are right, some of the signatures are slightly different. I will go through them 1 by 1

Comment: You need to make sure `static_cast<INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf*> != nullptr` is valid for whichever class you list `INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf` in the com map.

Comment: @RichardCritten I declared the interface in the IDL file and still no luck, same errors as before

Comment: `CNvRtrProtocolXxxImpl` must derive from `INvRtrProtocolEx3Itf` in your C++ code. The interface doesn't have to be mentioned in the IDL, but it does need to appear in the C++ class definition.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with _IDTExtensibility2. In my case the solution proposed on [this page](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/04/09/fix-cannot-convert-from-cconnectproxy_commapclass-to-addindesignerobjectsidtextensibility2/) fixed the issue.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Designer
regsvr32 MSADDNDR.dll
```

And then the compilation magically works.